# MySQL: Use field content in where clause

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

Let's say I have a table with a `date_last_action` (datetime) and a `frequency` (varchar) field. The latter contains a string representing a valid [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) period (example: "1 WEEK", "1 YEAR").

Now I want to retrieve all records where the time has passed.

This is what I am trying:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
where DATE_ADD(`date_last_action`,INTERVAL `frequency`) < now()
```

This does not work. I get:

```
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near ') < now()'
```

I am sure it is related to that `frequency`.

**How can this be done?**

Obviously, I could do two calls    - first retrieve the frequency, then check if the row is "outdated". But I guess that would use a lot more resources if I expect only few records to match.

Comment: It seems that's not the way that function works.  The unit specifier is required, and it's not a string, so you can't actually feed it from the database this way.  You have to know the increment unit at the time you write the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL expects a keyword after INTERVAL and not any string or numeric value. You can achieve what you want by using a CASE statement and give the different cases with the different keywords.

As an example, let's say you want to add the value with the appropriate unit to the date then the SQL statement would be as follows:

```
SELECT CASE unit
       WHEN "DAY" THEN date_add(date, INTERVAL value DAY)
       WHEN "MONTH" THEN date_add(date, INTERVAL value MONTH)
       END
       AS newDate
FROM table
```

But you will need another column with `unit`!

Also works in the WHERE clause...

Comment: @IanMcLaird I've edited my answer cause i had understood  wrong. Sorry

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it works - albeit not as simply as I originally hoped. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/567ac/1/0